# WhatsApp Business API: "There was an error verifying this phone number"

Tags: facebook, docker, docker-compose, whatsapp, facebook-apps

I'm working on WhatsApp API Business. So... I did registered the docker container some times before, but I had to reinstall them and this time I was unable to register the container again. When I try to request a register code I receive this kind os response:

```
POST {{URL}}/v1/account

{
    "meta": {
        "api_status": "stable",
        "version": "2.19.4"
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 1005,
            "title": "Access denied",
            "details": "There was an error verifying this phone number. Please try again later."
        }
    ]
}
```

I checked if the docker containers are running and everything looks like working well.

```
[root@xxxx 2-19-4]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
bee4beefa6e7        docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v2.19.4       "/opt/whatsapp/bin/w…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:9090->443/tcp                2-19-4_waweb_1
a52b9c98e2f2        docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v2.19.4   "/opt/whatsapp/bin/w…"   About an hour ago   Up 23 minutes       6250-6253/tcp                        2-19-4_wacore_1
13a961e53501        mysql:5.7.22                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33060->3306/tcp   2-19-4_db_1
```

Anyone that passed and fixed this before could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out the Facebook team and looks like something had wrong in their side. I did get the following response from the Facebook team and after this everything is working well.

[image]